# Insert and Search in Datetime field

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to insert a date with milliseconds but I can't do it after insert the following format with bash:

```
"%d%m%Y%H%M%S%2N"
```

While in BBDD I see the following:

```
MariaDB [db]> INSERT INTO access_wifi(DATA) VALUES ('0511201813450367');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [db]> select * from access_wifi;
+----+------------------------+
| id | DATA                   |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.00 |
|  2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.00 |
|  3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00.00 |
+----+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What command should the correct to insert/search?

Update with this information:

```
MariaDB [db]> DESCRIBE access_wifi;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| DATA  | datetime(2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

Comment: Edited the question to remove the `mysql` tag as its only relevant to `mariadb`...

Comment: also if you want custom datetime format, probably better to make col type varchar and then manipulate that way (I could be wrong - someone lemme know if the case)

Comment: update the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Str_to_Date()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/str_to_date/) function, in order to convert your custom datetime string to MariaDB/MySQL datetime format (**yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.xxxxx**)

```
INSERT INTO access_wifi(DATA) 
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('0511201813450367', '%d%m%Y%H%i%s%f'));
```

**Details:**

- `%d` Day with 2 digits.
- `%m` Month with 2 digits.
- `%Y` Year with 4 digits.
- `%H` Hour with 2 digits between 00-23.
- `%i` Minute with 2 digits.
- `%s` Seconds with 2 digits.
- `%f` Sub seconds (miroseconds) 6 digits.

Comment: @GuifIf happy to help :)